# Images under mappings in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]Find the image under the mapping of the following. I tried to figure out how to do these problems but to no avail. I have tried Question 1 and 2. Question 3 and 4 seem to be confusing. Do I need to use linear transformation for that?

Is there any particular way in finding the images?

Comment: Apparently, it's better to substitute$z=x+iy$ and $w=u+iv$ and do calculates.

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures cannot be searched and are inaccessible to those using screen readers.

Comment: @Maryam, I did that for Question 1 and 2. But 3 and 4 seem to be a bit different. Do I need to use linear transformation?

Comment: @Lord_Farin, well noted. I am still learning how to type using Latex. But appreciate your concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part 2: take $z=x+iy$ and $w=u+iv$ then substitute them into map. we have
$$u=e^x\cos y,~v=e^x\sin y$$
where $x<0$ and $0\leq y\leq\pi$, these conclude $e^x<1,0\leq\sin y\leq1,-1\leq\cos y\leq1$ and then $-1\leq u\leq1,0\leq v\leq1$, also
$$|w|^2=u^2+v^2=e^{2x}\leq1$$
then the answer is upper semicircle with redius 1, that is $|w|\leq1$ because $0\leq v\leq1$.

Comment: @Many thanks. I did same as well. But Question 3 and 4 are my major worry... How do I go about it?

Comment: For these two case, note that they are bilinear transforms and you know a bilinear transformation maps circles and straight lines 
onto circles and straight lines. In part (3) you see a circle isn't pass from origin so $\displaystyle\frac{1-z}{1+z}$ maps semicircle to a semiline which obtain by these points $$(1,0) goes to (0,0)$$ $$(-1,0) goes to \infty$$ $$i goes to -i$$ after that we have a line pass from points 0 and $\displaystyle(-i)^\frac23=(\frac12-i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ and it's done.

Comment: shouldn't (1,0) go to (1,0) instead? And does it mean the semicircle maps to a diagonal line in the fourth quadrant?